# Connection forms associatedwith the Levi-Civita connection

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections

Say we have a Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ of dimension $3$ with an orthonormal frame $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^3$. Denote by $\theta^i$ the associated dual basis, that is, $\theta^i(e_j)=\delta_i^j$ for every $i,j=1,2,3$. Then, the connection $1$-forms $\omega_j^i$ associated with the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ will satisfy the equations
$$d\theta^i=-\sum_{j=1}^3 \omega_j^i \wedge \theta^j,$$
and
$$\nabla_{e_i}e_j=\sum_{k=1}^3 \omega_j^k(e_i)e_k.$$
My question is if the $\omega_j^i$ will span the cotangent space $T^*M$. I have used this property to actually compute $\omega_j^i$ in some excersises, and it always is the case that the $\omega_j^i$ span $T^*M$, but I don't know if this is true.

Comment: No, for obvious reasons that in $\Bbb{R}^n$ with the trivial connection in the standard coordinate system all connection forms vanish identically.

Comment: If you’re working in an orthonormal frame, then the defining property of the connection 1-forms is that they satisfy the structural equation you wrote, and the matrix of 1-forms $(\omega^{i}_{\,j})$ is skew-symmetric (assuming $g$ is Riemannian; for other signatures, it is $\omega_{ab}:=g_{ai}\omega^i_{\,b}$ which is skew-symmetric (this encodes metric-compatibility)).

Comment: @peek-a-boo To me, the defining property is simply $\nabla e_j = \omega^i_j \otimes e_i$, and what you said is a characterization. Are there references where the connection $1$-form is explicitly defined by Cartan's structural equations?

Comment: @Didier i meant characterization of the connection forms of the Levi-Civita connection.